# How can I update a table based on the result of a join?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Heres what I've tried based on similar questions:

```
UPDATE Workforce 
   SET Workforce.Deactivated = Yes
  FROM Workforce LEFT JOIN WorkersLast30Days 
    ON Workforce.[WorkforceID] = WorkersLast30Days.[WorkerID]
 WHERE (((WorkersLast30Days.WorkerID) Is Null));
```

Using MS Access.

Workforce is a table, Deactivated is a column in it (yes/no)
WorkersLast30Days is another query that gives the IDs I dont want to update.

Comment: What happens when this is run - error message, wrong result, nothing?

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator in query expression 'Yes
  FROM Workforce LEFT JOIN WorkersLast30Days 
    ON Workforce.[WorkforceID] = WorkersLast30Days.[WorkerID]'

Comment: Try to replace `Yes` by `True` or `-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Access, try this:

```
UPDATE Workforce 
   SET Workforce.Deactivated = 'Yes'
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM  WorkersLast30Days 
                     WHERE Workforce.[WorkforceID] = WorkersLast30Days.[WorkerID]
                    );
```

Comment: Almost! had to change 'Yes' to -1

UPDATE Workforce 
   SET Workforce.Deactivated = -1
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM  WorkersLast30Days 
                     WHERE Workforce.[WorkforceID] = WorkersLast30Days.[WorkerID]
                    );

Comment: @SamLX . . . The question explicitly uses `Yes`.

Comment: you are correct -  in my original question I had put 'yes' however it was actually a mistake and I got a type error when it executed. Changing to -1 solved that problem and gave the desired result.